# Two phase implicit casting in c++

Tags: c++, casting

Isn't there something in the c++ standard that states I can implicitly cast two time? i.e. in case my function takes object A and I call it with object C I wont get compilation error even if there is no direct cast between C and A but there is a cast from C to B and from B to A? At some point in life I though this code was legal but today I found out I was wrong.

```c
class A { };

class B 
{
    A m_a;
public:
    operator A () { return m_a; }
};

class C 
{
    B m_b;
public:
    operator B () { return m_b; }
};


void f(A a){ }

int main()
{
    C c;
    f(c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: BTW you're missing an `operator A` in class `B`

Comment: There are no **casts** in this code. There are **implicit conversions**. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An implicit conversion can only involve a single user-defined conversion. It can also contain built-in conversions (such as `int` to `long`) before and/or after the user-defined conversion.

Your code is not valid since it would require two user-defined conversions, `C` to `B` to `A` (assuming that you meant to say `operator A` not `operator int` in `B`). There's a good reason for this: to allow two conversions, the compiler would have to try every possible intermediate type, and there are an infinite number of possible types.

By the way, there are no casts involved here. A cast is an *explicit* type conversion.

Comment: So it can be two-phase if one of them is a built-in conversion?

Comment: @Mehrdad: Yes, as long as the conversion is unambiguous. If `C` were convertible to `int` (and no other integer types), and `f` wanted a `long`, then `f(C)`, converting `C` to `int` to `long`, would be fine.

Comment: OK, thanks for refereshing my memory, now I get it, one user defined and one built in

Comment: One comment about the reason you mentioned, I'm not sure there are infinite number of types, and if there were, then even one conversion would cause compilation to run forever. Given there are `n` possible types we are looking at `n^2` possible conversions.

Comment: @e271p314: The set of types includes `void`, `void*`, `void**`, etc., which is infinite. With only one conversion, there's no need to check all types: the compiler knows the type of the expression being converted, and the type being converted to, so there's no need to consider other types at all.

Comment: OK, got that, I was totally wrong, with one conversion you need to check only one combination

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to convert `C` to `A`, the conversion operator actually needs to be A, not B. You get a B, but it doesn't turn into an A without casting. However, returning B as an A will do an implicit conversion.

```
class C 
{
    B m_b;
public:
    operator A () { return m_b; }
};
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/835496f4c4a2df92)

Comment: OK, I get it, implicit conversion is returning an object of one type while the operator's return type is different